# How to load variable form one form to another form developed in IDE in different documents

Tags: c#, windows, variables

Does anybody know how to load variable form one form to another form developed in ID in different document?
I know how to do it if will I use:

```
Form form2 = new Form();
string DepartmentName = "IT";
...
```

But how to do it if are variables in different documents?

Comment: Do you mean you have a variable in one Form which you need to access from within another Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example you can change constructor in form2 to:

public class Form2 {
    string DepartmentName;

```
public Form2(string DepartmentName) {
    this.DepartmentName = DepartmentName;
}
```

}

And in other file:

```
 public class Form1 {
      void method() {
           Form2 form2 = new Form2(DepartmentName);
      }
 }
```

Also you can use static variables.